# Блок схема произведения элементов в массиве

Tags: алгоритм

Как в массиве из n элементов найти произведение элементов, расположенных между максимальными и минимальными значениями, блок схему составить надо.

Answer (score 4):

1й проход массива - определение максимального, минимального (индексы).
2й проход - подсчёт суммы от меньшего индекса до большего.

Comment: Только не суммы, а произведения.

Comment: А ну да, проглядел, но не суть важно.